# Tools for RE OpenCL Kernel

Tags: disassembly, tools, amd64, graphics

I have an OpenCL 2.0 program with various `.bin` files that I would like to reverse.  `file` shows:

```
$> file k.bin
k.bin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, *unknown arch 0x40c* version 1 (SYSV),
corrupted program header size, not stripped.
```

I believe these files to be OpenCL kernel files. Opening the file in `vim` shows many OpenCL references. At the end of the binary blob there are plaintext attributes like this:

```
uniqueid:1038
;memory:uavprivate:0
;memory:datareqd
```

What is the best current approach to disassemble these binaries?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `cuobjdump`, `nvdisasm`, or `nvprune`, three CUDA binary tools.
You can find a full explanation of how to use it on this [page](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html).

See also this [question in SO (Disassemble an OpenCL kernel?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689224/disassemble-an-opencl-kernel).